# How do I pass a rendered persistent/esqueleto query to another query?

Tags: haskell, yesod, esqueleto, haskell-persistent

I'd like to use Persistent/Esqueleto to implement count estimates.

One approach recommended in [this article](https://www.citusdata.com/blog/2016/10/12/count-performance/#:%7E:text=The%20previous%20section%20gets%20estimated%20counts%20for%20entire%20tables,%20but%20is%20there%20a%20way%20to%20get%20one%20for%20only%20those%20rows%20matching%20a%20condition?%20Michael%20Fuhr%20came%20up%20with%20a%20clever%20trick%20to%20run%20EXPLAIN%20for%20a%20query%20and%20parse%20its%20output.) is to define a function like this

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION count_estimate(query text) RETURNS integer AS $$
DECLARE
  rec   record;
  rows  integer;
BEGIN
  FOR rec IN EXECUTE 'EXPLAIN ' || query LOOP
    rows := substring(rec."QUERY PLAN" FROM ' rows=([[:digit:]]+)');
    EXIT WHEN rows IS NOT NULL;
  END LOOP;
  RETURN rows;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE STRICT;
```

and then use it like this

```sql
SELECT count_estimate('SELECT * FROM companies WHERE status = ''Active''');
```

In order to use the `count_estimate` function, I'll need (I think?) to render the query that Peristent/Equeleto generates, however when I try rendering the query with [`renderQuerySelect`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/esqueleto-3.5.3.0/docs/Database-Esqueleto-Experimental.html#v:renderQuerySelect), I get something like this

```
SELECT "companies"."id", "companies"."name", "companies"."status"
FROM "companies"
WHERE "companies"."status" IN (?)
; [PersistText "Active"]
```

This of course can't be stuffed into the `count_estimate`, because it will syntax error on the `?` placeholder. I also can't naïvely replace the `?` with `"Active"`, because it will syntax error on that first double quote.

How do I render the query in a way that my `count_estimate` function will accept?

I tried something like this, but it fails at runtime

```hs
getEstimate :: (Text, [PersistValue]) -> DB [Single Int]
getEstimate (query, params) = rawSql [st|
  SELECT count_estimate('#{query}');
  |] params
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to figure it out (mostly).

It's a matter of escaping the single quotes in both the query and the `PersistValue` parameters. I'm doing it like this at the moment, but escaping will need to be added back in otherwise I think it creates a SQL injection vulnerability. I may also need to handle the other `PersistValue` constructors in some specific way, but I haven't run into problems there yet.

```hs
import qualified Data.Text as T
import qualified Database.Persist as P

getEstimate :: (Text, [PersistValue]) -> DB (Maybe Int)
getEstimate (query, params) = fmap unSingle . listToMaybe <$> rawSql [st|
  SELECT count_estimate('#{T.replace "'" "''" query}');
  |] (map replace' params)
  where literal a = PersistLiteral_ P.Unescaped ("''" <> a <> "''")
        replace' = \case
          PersistText t -> literal $ encodeUtf8 t
          PersistDay  d -> literal $ encodeUtf8 $ pack $ showGregorian d
          a             -> a
```